# Countering tanks/assassins as a ranged character

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been playing LoL mostly as ranged (Annie and Heimerdinger), and if the other team happens to stack a couple of tanks/assassins, then I basically get slaughtered if I go after any critical point.

Are there any generic strategies that could be applied to be a credit to team?  Many times I will get stunned/snared/frozen and cannot run away, and just get cut to pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic strategies:

- Don't recall in unprotected spaces
- Don't scout bushes with your face
- Use Flash (summoner spell) to escape traps
- Use Cleanse (summoner spell) or Quicksilver Sash (item) to remove CC
- When running from traps, be aware of allies and plan accordingly
- Use items that boost Tenacity to reduce the duration of stuns
- Buy potions/lifesteal to remain at high health.  This helps to prevent ganks.
- Buy wards/use abilities (teemo's mushrooms) to maintain map control
- Don't overextend.  If you don't know what's in the bushes, stay away!
- When not laning, stick with another hero (but NOT another carry!)
- Call MIAs.  Consider using Skype, Mumble, etc to make this easier and more effective.
- Annie specific: Always keep your stun up.  Use spells to charge it at base, etc.

These are just some rough guidelines that apply to all characters, and are within your control.  If you find yourself being the target of an assassin, make sure your team knows it; a good team will anticipate this and assassinate the assassin.

Answer (score 5):

Your primary strategy has to be to pre-emptively not get caught out of position. As a ranged damage-dealing character, you are fragile and important to your team's success. You are a primary target, and must always be aware of where you are in relation to the enemies. In team fights, always keep an ally or two between you and the enemies. Use hit and run tactics, especially with mages like Heimerdinger and Annie, and retreat while your spells are on cooldown.

Ideally, your allies would also be protecting you. The longer you live, the more damage you're dealing, and the more helpful you are to your team. The tanks and off-tanks should be focused on making sure that you are alive and well, or else they're not doing their job properly either.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you should pay attention to when playing versus assassins are the other lanes, especially when playing mid. If top or bottom lane is getting pushed back a lot there is a huge chance that one of the assassins will come and gank mid. However if top and bottom lane are pushed towards the enemy most of the time you will be pretty save (watch junglers tho)

Also always make sure to ward! They exist for some reason! Plus you should be able to survive a gank as Annie and Heimer at low levels, because he is overpowered during the laning phase and Annie because she has a huge burst of damage - combine that with flash and you easily can get a free kill.